# Create new database from backup changing mdf and ldf path

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a series of manual job:

1. create new database specifying alternative `.mdf` and `.ldf` file locations.
2. restore a previous backup in the new database using alternative path defined above and overwriting everything

How can I do this? I've tried:

```
RESTORE DATABASE newdb 
FROM DISK = 'F:\Shared\newdb.bak'
WITH MOVE 'newdb' TO 'G:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\newdb.mdf',  
     MOVE 'newdb_log' TO 'G:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\newdb_log.ldf',
replace
```

but I got:

> Logical file 'newdb' is not part of database 'newdb'.
>   Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names.
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

And if I use `FILELISTONLY` I got another type of error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression or an xmlnamespaces clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: RESTORE FILELISTONLY DATABASE and  RESTORE DATABASE FILELISTONLY

Comment: It's `RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK ......` - see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use find out the **logical names** using:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
FROM DISK = 'F:\Shared\newdb.bak'
```

This gives you all the logical files contained in the backup, and their logical names.

With that information, you should be able to build up your `RESTORE DATABASE` command properly.

See the [relevant MSDN SQL Server Books Online documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Logical name was completly different from my expectations.
Just one question, how can I make a sort of select on that results? If I only need logical name for field==D what can I do?